# Read a zip file inside zip file

Tags: java, file, zip, unzip

I have zip file which is inside a  folder in zip file please suggest me how to read it using zip input stream.

E.G.:

```
abc.zip
    |
      documents/bcd.zip
```

How to read a zip file inside zip file?

Comment: what do you mean by read? do you want to extract bcd.zip?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to look through zip files within zip files recursively,

```
    public void lookupSomethingInZip(InputStream fileInputStream) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(fileInputStream);
        String entryName = "";
        ZipEntry entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        while (entry!=null) {
            entryName = entry.getName();
            if (entryName.endsWith("zip")) {
                //recur if the entry is a zip file
                lookupSomethingInZip(zipInputStream);
            }
            //do other operation with the entries..

            entry=zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
        }
    }
```

Call the method with the file input stream derived from the file -

```
File file = new File(name);
lookupSomethingInZip(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Comment: I fixed broken recursion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54861562/5777603 Thanks Manas Maji for idea :)

Answer (score 5):

The following code snippet lists the entries of a ZIP file inside another ZIP file. Adapt it to your needs. [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) uses [`ZipInputStream`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) underneath the hood.

The code snippet uses [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), specifically [`IOUtils.copy`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream%2C%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

```
public static void readInnerZipFile(File zipFile, String innerZipFileEntryName) {
    ZipFile outerZipFile = null;
    File tempFile = null;
    FileOutputStream tempOut = null;
    ZipFile innerZipFile = null;
    try {
        outerZipFile = new ZipFile(zipFile);
        tempFile = File.createTempFile("tempFile", "zip");
        tempOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        IOUtils.copy( //
                outerZipFile.getInputStream(new ZipEntry(innerZipFileEntryName)), //
                tempOut);
        innerZipFile = new ZipFile(tempFile);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = innerZipFile.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            System.out.println(entry);
            // InputStream entryIn = innerZipFile.getInputStream(entry);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Make sure to clean up your I/O streams
        try {
            if (outerZipFile != null)
                outerZipFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(tempOut);
        if (tempFile != null && !tempFile.delete()) {
            System.out.println("Could not delete " + tempFile);
        }
        try {
            if (innerZipFile != null)
                innerZipFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    readInnerZipFile(new File("abc.zip"), "documents/bcd.zip");
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, exactly what i wanted and was breaking my head for hours together. You made my day. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that it is possible to do it without a temporary file. You will have to instantiate an original `ZipInputStream` from the `"abc.zip"` file then open a new `ZipInputStream` for the `ZipEntry` corresponding to the file `"documents/bcd.zip"`. Make sure to wrap  the original `ZipInputStream` with an `InputStream` that avoids closing the `InputStream` managed by the new `ZipInputStream`. The only `InputStream` you will need to close is the original one.

Comment: Great, but 3 Mb only for `IOUtils.copy` function, which have 2 strings, seriosly?

Answer (score 3):

Finally got it to work fixing Manas Maji's answer. Minimal solution:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import org.slf4j.*;

public void readZipFileRecursive(final Path zipFile) {
  try (final InputStream zipFileStream = Files.newInputStream(zipFile)) {
    this.readZipFileStream(zipFileStream);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("error reading zip file %s!", zipFile, e);
  }
}

private void readZipFileStream(final InputStream zipFileStream) {
  final ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zipFileStream);
  ZipEntry zipEntry;
  try {
    while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
      LOG.info("name of zip entry: {}", zipEntry.getName());
      if (!zipEntry.isDirectory() && zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
        this.readZipFileStream(zipInputStream); // recursion
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.error("error reading zip file stream", e);
  }
}
```

Care: don't close stream in recursive method.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a code that can unzip all zip files inside a zip file. It can even unzip to n levels of compression. Like for example if you had a zip file inside a zip, inside a zip ( and so on) it would extract all of them. Use the zipFileExtract method of this class and pass the source zip file and destination directory as an argument.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class RecursiveFileExtract {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    private static Queue<File> current;
    private static List<File> visited;

    public static void zipFileExtract(File sourceZipFile, File destinationDirectory) {
        Path temp = null;
        if(!destinationDirectory.exists())
        {
            destinationDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        try {
            temp = Files.move(Paths.get(sourceZipFile.getAbsolutePath()), Paths.get(destinationDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+sourceZipFile.getName()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File zipFile = new File(temp.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        current = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        visited = new ArrayList<>();
        current.add(zipFile);
        do {
            unzipCurrent();
            zipFinder(destinationDirectory);
        }
        while (!current.isEmpty());
    }

    private static void zipFinder(File directory) {
        try {
            if (directory != null) {
                File fileArray[] = directory.listFiles();
                if (fileArray != null) {
                    for (File file : fileArray) {
                        if (file != null) {
                            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                                zipFinder(file);
                            } else {
                                if (file.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
                                    if (!visited.contains(file)) {
                                        current.add(file);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void unzipCurrent() {
        try {
            while (!current.isEmpty()) {
                File file = current.remove();
                visited.add(file);
                File zipDirectory = new File(file.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());
                unzip(file.getAbsolutePath(), zipDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) {
        try {
            ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
            ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();

            while (entry != null) {
                String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
                if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                    extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
                } else {

                    File dir = new File(filePath);
                    Boolean result = dir.mkdir();
                }
                zipIn.closeEntry();
                entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
            }
            zipIn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) {
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            File parentFile = file.getParentFile();
            if (!parentFile.exists()) {
                Boolean result = parentFile.mkdirs();
                if (!result) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
            }
            bos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```