# List .zip directories without extracting

Tags: java, zip

I am building a file explorer in Java and I am listing the files/folders in JTrees. What I am trying to do now is when I get to a zipped folder I want to list its contents, but without extracting it first.

If anyone has an idea, please share.

Comment: This snippet does exactly what this question aks for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54861562/5777603

Answer (score 25):

I suggest you have a look at [`ZipFile.entries()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries%28%29).

Here's some code:

```
try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("test.zip")) {
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
    while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
        String fileName = zipEntries.nextElement().getName();
        System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}
```

If you're using **Java 8**, you can avoid the use of the almost deprecated `Enumeration` class using `ZipFile::stream` as follows:

```
zipFile.stream()
       .map(ZipEntry::getName)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

If you need to know whether an entry is a directory or not, you could use [`ZipEntry.isDirectory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory%28%29). You can't get much more information than that without extracting the file (for obvious reasons).

---

If you want to **avoid extracting *all* files,** you can extract one file at a time using [`ZipFile.getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29) for each `ZipEntry`. (Note that you don't need to store the unpacked data on disk, you can just read the input stream and discard the bytes as you go.

Comment: Since java 7, I'd say using NIO via the `FileSystem`, `Path` and `Files` is a much easier (and unified way) or solving this problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37413531/80779 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/37413128/80779

Answer (score 10):

Use `java.util.zip.ZipFile` class and, specifically, its `entries` method.

You'll have something like this:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("testfile.zip");
Enumeration zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
String fname;
while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    fname = ((ZipEntry)zipEntries.nextElement()).getName();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but i have to know what types of files are in it, this will pretty much just give me the names of the files/folders, i have to know if it is a file, a folder etc.

Answer (score 1):

For handling ZIP files you can use class [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html). It has method [entries()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries%28%29) which returns list of entries contained within ZIP file. This information is contained in the ZIP header and extraction is not required.