# Putting files within a zip folder into an array of strings by path

Tags: java, arrays, zip, extract, jfilechooser

First the user browses for the zip file containing their Java project using a JFileChooser which is limited to .zip extension only.

Then I want all the file paths to be stored as strings in an array.

Browse... button:

```
btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File zip = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            // This is where the I need help.
        }
    }
});
```

So my array will be like this:

[path\to\java\file, path\to\java\file, path\to\java\file, path\to\java\file]

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Is there actually a problem with your code? You haven't mentioned one.

Comment: You can start here - [ZipFile.entries](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries()).

Comment: Are you saying that names of the files should be array ?

Comment: @Jābir not just the file names, the entire path.

Comment: @DaveRlz No it's not a problem, I'm just just wondering if people can help reach a solution for the intended task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this method to get list of selected files.

```
File[] zipFiles = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
```

and then

```
for (File file : zipFiles )
  {
      System.out.println(file .getAbsoluteFile()); // will print path
      // Add to array here
  }
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what I wanted to achieve, this would just print the path of each zip file, I want to get the paths of the files WITHIN the zip file.

Comment: Look at following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468163/list-zip-direcotries-without-extracting-java

Comment: This[http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8362] tutorial has a detailed explanation of how to handle zip files including listing files in it

Comment: Great resource! I now have an ArrayList with all the file names in. So I'm very close to what I want but I'm finding it hard to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [`java.util.zip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package out. It
provides classes for reading and writing the standard `ZIP` and `GZIP` file formats.