# Recursive read ZipFile without extracting (Java)

Tags: java

got a small problem. I have a ZipFile with unknown structure. I have to print on console all file entries. The main problem is that this main ZipFile may contain 'sub' ZipFiles, and these sub ZipFiles ma contain their own ZipFiles and so on. I just need to view all files entries but now extracting them.
I tried to use ZipFile and ZipInputStream but was not succeed.
Could some one help me?

```
public void showTree(ZipFile file) {
    try {
        ZipEntry entry;
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries= file.entries();
        while ((entry = entries.nextElement()) != null) {
            if (entry.getName().matches(".+(zip)$")) { 
                ZipFile z = new ZipFile(entry.getName()); //DOES NOT WORK!!!!!!
                showTree(z);
            }
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my code, I tied to create ZipFile from entry.getName() (does not work obviously), but was not succeed. The question is - how can I get entries from inner ZipFile?

Comment: Will you please share related code which is not working correctly?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287486/read-a-zip-file-inside-zip-file

Comment: Thanks! I saw that post, but now realized that this is exactly my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check "has child" for every layer you step into and if true you need to step deeper. once it has no more children you read the content and look for siblings. if there are siblings - well: step into them. otherwise your recursive methd will end there and step out to the upper call of the recursive metohd.

zipFile.recursiveMethod() or maybe recursiveMethod(zipFile) initiates the logic.
Like:

```
recursiveMethod(params)
{
     if(hasChild)
     {
         child.recursiveMethod();
     }
     // in deepest childObject
     readContent();
     if(hasSibling)
     {
         sibling.recursiveMethod();
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly my problem. I attached some code with additional explaination.

Comment: @Unknown posted the correct solution for your problem with his referral to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287486/read-a-zip-file-inside-zip-file
there you create the zip and "get entries from inner ZipFile".
Parent--> tempFile = File.createTempFile("tempFile", "zip");
Child--> innerZipFile = new ZipFile(tempFile);
Read child entries --> Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = innerZipFile.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) { code }

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for!