# How to read a file from a path containing two or more zipfiles in between?

Tags: java, zip, java.nio.file

Assume I have a path:

/path/to/zipfile.zip/my/earfile.ear/plainfile

where zipfile.zip is a zip file, and earfile.ear is a ear file. The presence of those compressed files are arbitrary.

I want to have a method which takes this kind of path as param and return an input stream or reader for the 'plainfile'.

I heard that it is easier to implement in Java 7 but I don't know how.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check if this helps [Read a zip file inside zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287486/read-a-zip-file-inside-zip-file)

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a way to solve this problem with restricted condition, which is that there are exactly two zip files are allowed.

```
public BufferedReader testNestedZipEntry() {
    try {
        // first zip file wrapped by ZipFile, which allows random access(just feed a path!) to find an entry
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("/path/to/zipfile.zip");
        // second zip file wrapped by ZipInputStream, which is sequential so you have to iterate over entries to find the one you need
        ZipEntry jarZipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("earfile.ear");
        ZipInputStream jarZipIn = new ZipInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(jarZipEntry));
        ZipEntry curEntry = null;
        while( (curEntry=jarZipIn.getNextEntry()) != null){
            // getNextEntry() method "positions" the input stream to curEntry
            // this is the reason why we can achieve this without extracting the file out
            if(curEntry.getName().equals("plainfile")) {
                return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jarZipIn)); 
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Tip for beginners: Entries in a zip file is all the files you can reach in the whole zip file, not only the ones in the root directory of the zip file.

Comment: inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287486/read-a-zip-file-inside-zip-file